# BJT - BC547 not working with LED strip

Tags: led, voltage, transistor

I'm connecting an LED strip that takes 12V input to an `Arduino Uno R3`'s `5V` VCC using a `B547` transistor. 
Here's my circuit:

```
Base -> 1K ohm resistor -> DO13
Collector -> -ve of LED strip
Emitter -> GND
VCC 5V -> +ve of LED strip
```

Nothing happens when I try to turn on the LED strip. However if I remove the 1K resistor and turn on the LED, Arduino's built in LED gets dimmer but the LED strip does not turn on.

What am I doing wrong? 
TIA!

Comment: What kind of LED strip? You can't run a typical 12V LED strip from 5V. Not even slightly.

Comment: @Majenko, thanks for the reply. I'm giving 12V current to the Arduino using an adapter. I just got the LED strip to shine dimly. Would it work if I lower the base resistance of the transistor or if I change the `VCC` to `VIN` instead of `5V`?

Comment: Please show a photograph of your actual setup.

Comment: @Qumber do not pass the LED supply current through the arduino ... there is a chance that the arduino will act as an expensive fuse

Comment: there's a nice circuit diagram tool that will help us diagnose your problem better. Generally though, to switch 12 volts with the Arduino, I would connect 12 v to collector pin, base to arduino IO pin, and emitter to ground. Also you should check if your transistor can handle the power requirement of the LED strip or else it will burn out

Comment: I'll definitely make a diagram and share in a bit. :)

Comment: BC547 is good for 100 mA only

Comment: You have a 12 Volt LED strip and power it with 5V. That could be the reason why the lights shine dimmy.  The transistor is not made for driving big loads. It's collector power dissipation is specified with 500 mW. I would recommend to use a MOSFET and use the 12 Volt Powersupply at the Strips V+ directly.

Comment: Connecting the `+` of the leds strip to VIN will give the strip 12V. Definitely don't connect the 12V adapter to Vcc, or you'll blow up the Arduino. Also, don't remove the 1k resistor, or you'll damage the Arduino's output pin. You can try lowering the value, but don't go below 220 Ohm. Though, unless your led strip is very short, the BC547 isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll replace `BC547` with a MOSFET and will try giving the strip its 12 volts from an external source instead of Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. First off, if you have a 12V LED strip then you have to power it from 12V. Powering the Arduino from 12V and then powering the LED strip from the 5V pin of the Arduino is *not* powering the LED strip from 12V, it's powering the Arduino from 12V and the LED strip from 5V.

The LED strip's anode (+) must be connected to the + of the 12V supply or, if it's only a very short LED strip then you can use VIN on the Arduino.

LED strips typically have a number of LEDs (eg 3) in series with a resistor to make one "segment", and many "segments" in parallel. This gives a total forward voltage of typically 9V or more - so you must provide *at least* that to get the LEDs to light.

Secondly the BC547 is not a good transistor to use for switching an LED strip.  It has a maximum continuous collector current of 100mA. That means that you can only have a maximum of 100mA going through your LED strip before the transistor blows.

For reference, 100mA is the equivalent of 5 "normal" (5mm, of the kind you'd use in a breadboard) LEDs at full current and brightness. A typical LED strip (depending on length) can use many hundreds or thousands of mA.

Really you should be using an N-channel MOSFET that is rated for *at least* as much current as your LED strip requires to run. For safety, and to reduce heat dissipation, you ideally want it to be many times more powerful than the LED strip needs.

A common choice is the IRF530, which is rated at 10A with a switching voltage (the "threshold" voltage) that is low enough for a 5V Arduino to control (there are more suitable ones, but these seem to be the "go-to" component for many Arduino users - they're adequate for most uses).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhSkWC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer. I do understand (a bit) the schematics now. I'll get my hands on the MOSFET, and will try it out as soon as I get home. :)

Comment: I gave the strip 12V directly and switched BC547 with a TIP120 and it did work. I'll try a small 12V LED powering up from VIN as well. Thanks for the help. This was my first ever project. :)